# Story where humans had the carbon in their cells replaced with silicon to make them stronger

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to remember the name of a sci-fi story, maybe novella, I lost while I was reading. It involved a war where the cells of humans had the carbon replaced with silicon to make them stronger(?) I lost the book about 25 years ago before I finished reading the story.

Comment: Can you remember any more details, like the general setting or nature of the story? Was this replacement done to all humans or just a few?

Comment: Who were they fighting? Do you remember any details about the characters? Was it set in space or on a planet?

Comment: Masters Of Space by E.E.Smith? "Jarvis Hilton is in charge of a handpicked team of scientists-and a navy warship on a deep space mission,dubbed Project Theta Orionis. On the outbound journey,automatic sensors drop their ship into normal space for an encounter with a mysterious skeletal object. The encounter leaves them baffled,and leads them to a view an epic space battle. But strange as that is, it's nowhere near as mysterious as finding a planet covered in radioactive fuel ore - and populated with humanoid robots who have been expecting their arrival and greet them as returning masters.

Comment: Escape across the Cosmos by Gardner Fox, sort of fits the question; Karl Carrick, a wounded survivor of an Interplanetary war, has his cells/organs replaced by silicon organs. He's exiled to a desolated planet for the framed murder of the genius who did the replacement

Comment: Max C. Sheridan's novelette "The Human Equation" fits the description, but it appeared in the [February 1939 issue](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61711) of *Thrilling Wonder Stories* and apparently was never reprinted; so unless the book you read it in 25 years ago was a 50-year-old pulp magazine, this is not the story you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'll follow up these leads and let you know. Unfortunately, @Joe, I read so many sci-fi stories as a teenager (I've got about four boxes of anthologies sitting in the garage) that I can't tease out any more details at the moment.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. I followed Escape Across the Cosmos, and ended up finding Titans of the Universe, which turns out to be a complete rip-off of Escape Across the Cosmos. Titans of the Universe is the one I remember, so thanks @Ken. http://www.peterdavid.net/2012/09/28/where-man-peter-and-more/

Comment: Mark, I re-entered my comment as an answer. I sort of remembered that whole rip-off thing from way back. I'm glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape across the Cosmos by Gardner Fox, fits the question; Karl Carrick, a wounded survivor of an Interplanetary war, has his cells/organs replaced by silicon organs. He's exiled to a desolated planet for the framed murder of the genius who did the replacement 
Escape Across the Cosmos was plagiarized twice as; Titans of the Universe by James Harvey and Star Chase by Brian James Royal. There is a dedication in Star Chase to James Harvey! Royal and Harvey are presumed to be the same person.

[image][image]
[image]